# Sticky Footer Hides Content

Tags: html, css, flask

My footer won't go to the bottom of a specific page. Instead, it strays in the middle of `product-container`.

[image: footer doesn't show correctly. why is it not at the bottom of the page?]The basic code is as follows:

```
base.html:
<html>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div>
        <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a>
        <a href="{{ url_for('shop') }}">Shop</a>
        <a href="{{ url_for('cart') }}">Cart</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <body>
  <div id="app">
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
  </body>
  <footer>
    <nav>
      <div class="terms">
        <a href='/terms'>Terms of Service</a>
        <p>All Rights Reserved.</p>
        <p>Copyright © 2023</p>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</html>
```

```
shop.html:
...

{% block content %}
    <div class="product-container">
      {% for product in products %}
      <div onclick = "location.href='{{ url_for('product_detail', product_name = product.name) }}'" class="product">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = product.image_url) }}" alt="{{ product.name }} Image">
        <h2 class="product-title">{{ product.name }}</h2>
        <p class="product-price">${{ product.price }}</p>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
...
```

```
shop.css

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .product-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 300px);
    z-index: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}

.product {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```
main.css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 210px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  footer p, footer a {
    font-size: 12px!important;
  }

  body {
    min-height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    clear: both;
  }

  footer {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

I hope this is enough information. If there is anything I should change, let me know.

It appears that the .product-container doesn't register as a div. The footer only meets halfway.

I looked at more than a dozen articles (over 5 stack overflow). None of them resolved the issue.

You can find the whole code [here](https://replit.com/@ichang3765/archieswag).

Comment: What about using `position:fixed` rather than `position:sticky` in `footer` class ?

Comment: New main.css to:
```
/* html, body  */
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 210px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  footer p, footer a {
    font-size: 12px!important;
  }

  body {
    min-height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    clear: both;
  }

  footer {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```
It didn't work

Comment: It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to reduce the style sheet code to the bare essentials. This makes it easier for you to find a possible error.

To prevent content from overlaying the footer, you should remove lines containing `z-index: 1;`.

In addition, the size of the images must be limited to the parent element. For this I added the following code.

```css
.product > img {
   object-fit: cover;
   width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
}
```

If there is not enough content to display, there is a risk that the footer will slide up. To prevent this, assign the following properties so that the `body` element has the minimum size and the `#app` container grows.

```css
body {
   /* ... */
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   min-height:100vh;
}

#app {
   /* ... */
   flex:1;
}
```

All changes can be found in the code sections below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {% block head -%}
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
    {% endblock -%}
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a>
            <a href="{{ url_for('shop') }}">Shop</a>
            <a href="{{ url_for('cart') }}">Cart</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="app">
        {% block content -%}{% endblock -%}
    </div>
    <footer>
        <nav class="terms">
            <a href='/terms'>Terms of Service</a>
            <p>All Rights Reserved.</p>
            <p>Copyright © 2023 - Archie Swag</p>
        </nav>
    </footer>
    {% block scripts -%}
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock -%}
</body>
</html>
```

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Shop{% endblock %}

{% block head -%}
    {{ super() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='shop.css') }}">
{% endblock -%}

{% block content -%}
    <div class="product-container">
        {% for product in products -%}
        <a href="{{ url_for('product_detail', product_name=product.name) }}" class="product">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=product.image_url) }}" alt="{{ product.name }} Image">
            <h2 class="product-title">{{ product.name }}</h2>
            <p class="product-price">${{ product.price }}</p>
        </a>
        {% endfor -%}
    </div>
{%- endblock%}

{% block scripts -%}
    {{ super() }}
{% endblock -%}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: white;

  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  min-height:100vh;
}


header {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  padding: 10px;
}

header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: lightgray;
}


#app {
  margin: 2.4rem 1.2rem;
  flex:1;
}


footer {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

footer a {
  color: white! important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```css
.product-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-items: center;
}

.product {
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: back;
}

.product:active > *, 
.product:hover > *, 
.product:visited > * 
{
  color: black;
}

.product > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.product .product-title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 40px;
}

.product .product-price {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #04AA6D;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .product-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, why do my links on the shop page not work? See the demo at https://archieswag-ichang3765.replit.app/. It seems to work on a computer, but on the Replit live demo, it refuses to connect. In addition, it still doesn't resolve the issue. See the code above.

Comment: The `product-container` still has the property `z-index`. This should be removed. The `hero-section`, which also contains the element `product-container`, has a fixed size because of `height: 400`, so it cannot grow. Also remove this property. I couldn't tell that the links didn't work. It worked for me.

Comment: I fixed the issues. See them at https://replit.com/@ichang3765/archieswag#static/shop.css. However, the padding-bottom: 110px; that I used for #shop-container refuses to work. Why can't I get a bottom padding/margin?

Comment: Oh, and, by the way, thanks for your help so far. That's a +1 and I'll make sure to give you the bounty if this resolves my issue.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. You can add a padding or margin at the bottom of the #shop-container. When you define one, space is added around the element containing the search form. Is it that what you want?

Comment: No. I am trying to add space underneath the content of the page. Otherwise, the footer covers up the content.

Comment: Padding is just extra space around the edge. It doesn't fill the remaining space.
If the footer is the same size on every page, which is not currently the case for the cart page, you can remove the bottom padding for `#app` and set a minimum height. Since the header and footer together have a size of 215 pixels, define `min-height: calc(100vh – 215px);` for the `#app` element. If you set a padding or margin for the container itself, this value must also be deducted.

Answer (score 0):

[Sticky positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#sticky_positioning) works by being rendered at its normal position in flow. When the user scrolls up or down and the sticky container reaches the top or bottom of the viewport, the container then sticks in place at the top or bottom of the viewport.

If you want the footer to always be at the bottom of the viewport, then you should use [fixed positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#fixed_positioning). The container will be the height and width of its contents unless you declare height and/or width.

This snippet is from the code you provided:
(The applicable styles are when the viewport is less than 600px)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 210px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  footer p, footer a {
    font-size: 12px!important;
  }

  body {
    min-height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    clear: both;
  }

  footer {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .product-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 300px);
    z-index: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}

.product {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Shop</a>
      <a href="#">Cart</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id="app">
  <div class="product-container">
    <div onclick="location.href='#'" class="product">
      <img src="//placeholder.pics/svg/100" alt="{{ product.name }} Image">
      <h2 class="product-title">{{ product.name }}</h2>
      <p class="product-price">${{ product.price }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <nav>
    <div class="terms">
      <a href='#'>Terms of Service</a>
      <p>All Rights Reserved.</p>
      <p>Copyright © 2023</p>
    </div>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

This snippet changes `footer` to fixed and declares a width:

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 210px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  footer p, footer a {
    font-size: 12px!important;
  }

  body {
    min-height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    clear: both;
  }

  footer {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .product-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 300px);
    z-index: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}

.product {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Shop</a>
      <a href="#">Cart</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id="app">
  <div class="product-container">
    <div onclick="location.href='#'" class="product">
      <img src="//placeholder.pics/svg/100" alt="{{ product.name }} Image">
      <h2 class="product-title">{{ product.name }}</h2>
      <p class="product-price">${{ product.price }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <nav>
    <div class="terms">
      <a href='#'>Terms of Service</a>
      <p>All Rights Reserved.</p>
      <p>Copyright © 2023</p>
    </div>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

BTW, your [HTML structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Getting_started#anatomy_of_an_html_document) is incorrect, having `<body>` after `<header></header>` and `</body>` before `<footer>`. Additionally, there's no need to nest `div` inside `nav`; just apply the class to `nav`.

Comment: I tried all of your suggestions. None worked. Instead, the footer went to the end of the page and covered the content partly. margin-bottom and padding-bottom didn't work. In addition, I noticed the links for the header don't work specifically on the shop page.

Answer (score 0):

To put a html object on the bottom of a website simply set the position to absolute and the bottom to 10px which would make any html object go to the bottom

```
<h1 class="hola">hola</h1>
<style>
    .hola{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:10px;
    }
</style>
```